# Use embedded WLP to run Spring Boot application

Tags: spring-boot, websphere-liberty

We have been using embedded tomcat to run my Spring Boot applications.

We now want to use embedded Websphere Liberty Profile (WLP) to run the Spring Boot applications.

Is there a way to embed WLP similar to Tomcat and run instead of deploying the WAR as in traditional WAS deployments.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot does not support using WebSphere Liberty Profile as an embedded container. You can, however, build a war file and deploy it to a WLP server just as you can with any other external container.

WLP is not supported as there is no open source API that can be used to configure it. If you have a WLP licence and such an API is available then it may be possible to write your own `EmbeddedServletContainer` implementation but it would require a fairly significant amount of effort to do so.

Comment: Once you've deployed the spring boot app as a .war file you can package the server into a runnable jar file, so you can still have the java -jar experience, it is just a 2 step process. There is an example on how to do this in the micro profile conference vote micro service sample here: https://github.com/microprofile/microprofile-conference/blob/master/microservice-vote/pom.xml

Comment: Does the open source Liberty mean this can be plugged directly into Spring Boot?